# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::rowCount()

Tags: php, mysqli, count, fetch

I have a problem switching from MYSQL to MYSQLi. The codes work fine with MYSQL but when i change the connection to MYSQLi, I received the error as stated above when I'm fetching my query. How can i fetch my queries using mysqli functions?

Code:

```
        function __construct(){
    $this->link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax_rating');

    if (!$this->link) {
     die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($this->link) . "\n";

                }

    function getItems($id = null){
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'");
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM items");
        }
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowCount >= 1)
        {
            $result = $query->fetchAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `num_rows`

Read [MySQLi row_count](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.num-rows-examples)

So final answer would be

```
function getItems($id = null)
{
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM items");
    }
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;//change here
    if($rowCount >= 1)
    {
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
    }
    else
    {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**EDIT 01**

use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp) instead of `fetchAll()`

```
mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

so answer world be

```
    if($rowCount >= 1)
    {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: mm i've tried that earlier on but it gave me "Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()" I've researched around and it seems i need some sort of native driver?

Comment: That method had a name change. It's now called `mysqli_result::fetch_all()`. All the methods on a resultset object are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use num_rows for counting rows in DB and you can direct call connection like this :-

```
//for connection

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajax_rating");
if(!$con)
{
echo "connection error";
}


//query
function getItems($id = null)
 {
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'");
}
else
{
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items");
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)//change here
    {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
     {
       $result=$row;
     }

}
else
{
    $result = 0;
}
return $result;
}
```